# How to pass values to attributes in custom tags in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf

I am trying to create a custom tag file in jsf 1.2 with two attributes. I want to pass the values in these tags from the jsp page where this tag is used. how can this be done?

Comment: Hi... If anyone knows please let me know

Comment: I suggest you update your jsf version. jsf 2.2 is already released.

Answer (score 0):

JSF 1.2 specification required pretty a lot of work and several configuration files to be handled.But JSF 2.2 specifications is simpler compared to JSF 1.2.You can see this link find out a solution for custom tag....

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jsf/jsf-java-based-custom-tags-example

Comment: You're not answering the concrete question being asked. You're merely saying that it's hard in JSF 1.2 and that it's easier in JSF 2.2 along with code hidden behind a link which might not be reachable after some time (and thus rendering the whole answer completely useless). OP isn't interested in the JSF 2.2 approach. OP is interested in the JSF 1.2 approach. This "answer" is more appropriate as a comment on the question. Please earn a minimum of 50 reputation by posting true answers first, then you can post comments like this on someone else's questions if you really need to.